# How to get the integral of $\log(\det(A + Bt))$ w.r.t variable t?

Tags: integration, matrices, definite-integrals, applications

Suppose we have two positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$, now I want to get the integral of:

\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b} \log(\det(A + Bt)) dt ~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{for } a, b > 0 
\end{align}
Analytic solution is better, but good approximation is also acceptable here. I tried to approximate this integral via interpolation, but as $A$, $B$ are of large size (i.e, 100 × 100), that maybe too slow to calculate $\det(A + Bt)$ every time. When I seek the analytics solution, I met the problem of finding: $\frac{d(\det(A + Bt))}{dt}$. If you have any ideas or inference on this question, welcome to your answer and suggestions, thank so much!!

Answer (score 3):

In general, $\det X$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $X$ (counted with multiplicity). Note the eigenvalues of $I+X$ are $1+\lambda$ where $\lambda$s are the eigenvalues of $X$. Therefore

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \ln\det(A+Bt) & =\ln\big[\det A\,\det(I+A^{-1}Bt)\big] \\
& =\ln\det A+\ln\prod(1+\lambda t) \\ & = \ln\det A+\sum\ln(1+\lambda t). \end{array}$$

where $\lambda$s run over the eigenvalues of $X=A^{-1}B$.

A constant $\ln\det A$ is easy to integrate and $\ln(1+\lambda t)$ can be integrated elementarily, yielding

$$ t\ln\det A+\sum\left[\frac{1+\lambda t}{\lambda}\ln(1+t\lambda) - t\right]+C. $$

If $X$ is diagonalizable, this can be written as

$$ t\big(\ln\det A-n\big)+\mathrm{tr}\left[(B^{-1}A+t)\ln(I+tA^{-1}B)\right]+C, $$

presumably a density argument implies this also holds if $X$ is not diagonalizable (i.e. the expression above is continuous, and diagonalizable matrices are dense, so...)

Comment: Do the integration, the result will simplify a bit.

Comment: @reuns I don't see how $(\cdots)+\sum\frac{1+\lambda t}{\lambda}\ln(1+\lambda t)$ simplifies, if I'm honest.

Comment: Aren't there algorithms to compute $\log ( M)$ thus $tr((A^{-1}B)^{-1}\log (I+A^{-1}Bt))$ ? It is very possible that factoring approximatively the characteristic polynomial is better.

Comment: I think it would be ${\rm tr}\big[(X^{-1}+t)\ln(1+tX)\big]$, but I am not too familiar with matrix algorithms so I don't know of an algorithm to compute $\ln(I+M)$ that doesn't involve finding eigenvalues, or how such an algorithm would compare to just finding the eigenvalues.

Comment: I think the eigenvalues are better for a numerical evaluation but the $tr \log$ form is better to see the derivative in $A,B$